# jquery で　複数の別々のテキストをクリックしてテキスト内容を個別に変更＋ループ

Tags: jquery

初めまして。　jquery 初心者です。　
下記の参考サイトのような機能を実装したく、いろいろとwebで調べましたが、答えにたどり着けず困っております。　どなたか教えていただけると嬉しいです。

やりたいことというのは、下記のURLの通りなんですが、一点問題が発生しました。

※参考サイト（サンプル画面）
http://www.iltt.info/page/information/contents/20091105_sample.htm

※参考サイト（説明ページ）
http://www.iltt.info/page/information/contents/20091105.htm

問題というのは、たとえば、　生徒の一覧画面にAさん、Bさん、Cさん、Dさん　と並べて　各それぞれの人に対してボタン配置させた場合、上記のURLのままやると全員のテキストが同時に入れ変わってしまいます。

これを各自別々に作動するように分けたいのですが、いくら調べてもわかりませんでした。

同じクラスが指定されているので、全部一緒に入れ替わるという理屈は分かるのですが、別々にする作動する記述がどうしても分からないままです。

別々のclassやidに別けてで生徒の人数分のjsを書けば良いじゃないか！と言われるかと思いますが、それだと、人数が増えた文記述数も増えていくので、ほかに良い方法があるのではと思っています。

どなたかご教授いただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

追記＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
一点追記になります。
変更したいテキストというのは、住所、電話番号などの各自それぞれ別々データになります。

[例]

田中太郎君
クリック→　[東京都渋谷区]→[03-1111-1111]→ループ

吉岡二郎君
クリック→　[神奈川県横浜市]→[043-111-1111]→ループ

というようなイメージです

現状のコード＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

上記の参考URLを参考にしております。

```
山田太郎    
<div style="border: solid 1px #ccc">
    <div class="cm1">
        <p class="change "> 【契約住所】〒150-0002　東京都渋谷区渋谷</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cm2">
        <p class="change ">【電話番号】03-xxxx-1111</p>
    </div>
</div>

吉岡二郎
<div style="border: solid 1px #ccc">
    <div class="cm1">
        <p class="change ">【契約住所】〒150-0052　東京都渋谷区元代々木町</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cm2">
        <p class="change ">【電話番号】03-xxxx-2222</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

下記がスクリプトになります。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".change").click(function () {
            for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                if (i == 2) {
                    j = 1;
                } else {
                    j = i + 1;
                }
                if ($(".cm" + i).css("display") != "none") {
                    $(".cm" + i).hide();
                    $(".cm" + j).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 別々のdivを持たなくても単にテキストを配列で保持しておけばいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　それをどう記述すればいいのかが分からないのです。。

Comment: 参考にしているサイトは分かりましたが、現状のコードはどうなっているのですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。　追記分を追加しました。　よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

こういうこと？

```js
$(function () {
        $(".change").click(function (e) {
         //現在の要素を非表示
         $(e.target).parent().hide();
         //現在の要素を末尾に移動
         $(e.target).parent().parent().append($(e.target).parent());
         //先頭の要素を表示
         $(e.target).parent().parent().children("div:eq(0)").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

山田太郎 
<div style="border: solid 1px #ccc">
    <div>
        <p class="change"> 【契約住所】〒150-0002　東京都渋谷区渋谷</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
        <p class="change">【電話番号】03-xxxx-1111</p>
    </div>
</div>

吉岡二郎
<div style="border: solid 1px #ccc">
    <div>
        <p class="change">【契約住所】〒150-0052　東京都渋谷区元代々木町</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
        <p class="change">【電話番号】03-xxxx-2222</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: まさしくその通りです。　完璧です。　ありがとうございます！
今宵は美味いビールが飲めそうです。

たった4行でこのような動作が出来るなんて・・・
兎にも角にも、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

例えば以下のような感じ。
名簿のデータを

```
var db = [
    { name:"田中太郎君",   message:["東京都渋谷区", "03-1111-1111"] },
    { name:"吉岡二郎君",   message:["神奈川県横浜市", "043-111-1111"] },
    { name:"横尾陽子さん", message:["静岡県静岡市", "xxx-xxx-1111"] }
];
```

のような形で持ち、このデータから表示を作成します。
メッセージ部分にクリック時に実行する関数をクロージャー（メッセージ配列とインデックスを保持する：それぞれに保持する必要があるため）で割り当てます。

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>SAMPLE</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var db = [
 { name:"田中太郎君",   message:["東京都渋谷区", "03-1111-1111"] },
 { name:"吉岡二郎君",   message:["神奈川県横浜市", "043-111-1111"] },
 { name:"横尾陽子さん", message:["静岡県静岡市", "xxx-xxx-1111"] }
];
</script>
<style>
table#Roster { border-collapse: collapse; }
#Roster td { border: 1px black solid; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="Roster"></table>
<script>
function func(messages){
 var i = 0;
 return function(){
  i = (i + 1) % messages.length;
  $(this).text(messages[i]);
 };
}
$.each(db, function(index, value){
 var record = $("<tr></tr>")
  .append("<td>" + value.name + "</td>")
  .append($("<td>" + value.message[0] + "</td>").click(func(value.message)));
 $("#Roster").append(record);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: すごい・・・。　
また解析できていませんが、コピペしたら理想のカタチで出来ました。

ありがとうございます！　これで今夜はぐっすり寝れそうです。

Comment: @kazuya  この回答で解決したのであればVの部分をクリックして解決済みにして下さい。